# How can I delete all cell values at a specific range in Excel?

Tags: excel, formatting, conditional-statements

What I've been doing is I've made a correlation matrix in one of my databases with a total of 248 features. My objective is to remove all cells that has a correlation values between -0.5 to 0.5.  With the help of conditional formatting in Excel, I can highlight those values but I am wondering if I can delete all of the ones highlighted as well.

One of the ways that I've done is filtering the cells and delete the values that has correlation between -0.5 to 0.5 but it can only be done one column at a time which is time consuming for 248 features.  I've been searching if the find and replace feature can use a specified range as an input to find all values but I have not found any solutions. Also I'm new to macros so and haven't found the solution towards my problem thus far.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you replacing the values OR deleting the cells themselves? If you are deleting the cells, then how do you want the remaining cells to get rearranged (move left OR move up)? If the cells are not in a single row/column, the resulting cell positions may get scrambled (and not what you had in mind). Could you provide a sample of 2 or 3 rows and columns of data, if possible?

Comment: I just wanted the cells to be blank so yes, I do not want them to be rearranged.  I'll provide the sample in a few minutes

Comment: Here's what I've been trying to do.  The first three columns are the low correlations that I have already removed so I would like to leave them blank.
http://www.uppic.org/image-B407_57EE0604.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You can use a formula to edit out values outside your desired range:

`=IF(AND(0.5>A1,A1>-0.5),"",A1)`